# Is H2 gas produced when a mercury electrode is used as cathode in the electrolysis of Brine?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, electrochemistry, electrolysis

If platinum electrodes are used as electrodes, H2 gas and Cl2 gas are produced at the anode and cathode respectively.

[However, if a mercury electrode is used as the cathode, an exception is seen.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/17%3A_Electrochemical_Cells/17.03%3A_Electrolysis_of_Brine#:%7E:text=The%20sodium%20metal%20produced%20in%20this%20reaction%20dissolves%20in%20the%20liquid%20mercury%2C%20producing%20an%20amalgam.) Instead of H+ ions, Na+ ions are discharged first. This is because Na+ ions become mixed with mercury and form mercury amalgam (Hg.Na). As the mercury amalgam is formed, the tendency of Na+ ions to be reduced becomes greater than that of H+ ions. So, Na+ ions are discharged first.

My question is that after all the Na+ ions have been discharged, through the formation of Hg.Na, will H+ ions start to get discharged?

Comment: There is not meantioned the additional factor of high overpotertial for H+ reduction on Hg cathode.

Comment: @Poutnik Sir, I don't understand what overpotential is. Is the understanding of "overpotential" absolutely necessary?

Comment: But you do understood Google search, don't you ? [Overpotential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential)

Comment: And please don't say that the $\ce{Na+}$ ions become mixed in mercury. They don't. Only non-charged mercury atoms are soluble in mercury. Sodium ions are discharged at the mercury surface before being dissolved and form an amalgam.

Comment: @Maurice Oh, I see. So, Na atoms are soluble in mercury, not Na+ ions, right?

Comment: Yes. Metallic sodium is soluble in mercury, and not its ions.